# Sequelize setter error 'invalid input syntax for integer: "[object Object]"'

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to associate a list of contacts to a customer using the associations setter method, however, it always throws the error  'invalid input syntax for integer: "[object Object]"'.

The relevant query mentioned in the error is: `UPDATE "contactperson" SET "refCustomerId"=$1,"updatedAt"=$2 WHERE "id" IN ('[object Object]')`

This is how I use the setter:

```
db.customer.findByPk(customerID, {
            include: [{
                model: db.address,
                as: 'address',
            },{
                model: db.contactoption,
                as: 'contactOptions',
            }, {
                model: db.contactperson,
                as: 'contactPersons',
            }]
        }).then(customer => {
customer.setContactPersons([ { firstName: 'tester', lastName: 'tester', description: 'lorem ipsum' } ]);
});
```

This is the association:

```
Customer.hasMany(models.contactperson, {
  foreignKey: 'refCustomerId',
  as: 'contactPersons'
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I was thinking the error might be in "WHERE "id" IN ('[object Object]')2, shouldn't it show an array of integers rather than an object?

Comment: Sorry, yes, obviously! I completely read that wrong - was not awake enough yet, I guess !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue using the following code:

```
db.contactperson.bulkCreate([ { firstName: 'tester', lastName: 'tester', description: 'lorem ipsum' } ]).then(newContactPersons => {
    customer.setContactPersons(newContactPersons);
});
```

It's a more complicated approach than intended, but it get's the job done.

Comment: I used create to create just one entry.`const user = await User.findOne({ where: { uid:uid } })
const productUser = await Product.create(req.body)
await user.addProduct(productUser)`

Answer (score 1):

You used `set<ModelName>s` that just updates a link field of given records. If you need to create `contactperson` record you need to use `createContactPerson` instead of `setContactPersons` (NOTE: you cannot create several records at once).

```js
customer.createContactPerson({
  firstName: 'tester',
  lastName: 'tester',
  description: 'lorem ipsum'
});
```

compare to:

```
const contactPerson = db.contactperson.findById(1);
if (contactPerson) {
  customer.addContactPersons([contactPerson.id]);
}
```

`set<ModelName>s` - replaces old linked records with the new existing ones
`add<ModelName>s` - adds exisiting records in addition to old ones
`create<ModelName>` - create a new non-existing record in addition to old ones

See [hasMany special methods](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#-code-foo-hasmany-bar---code-)

Comment: Using addContactPersons yields the same result: [
  { firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Tester', description: 'Lorem ipsum' }
]
Executing (default): UPDATE "contactperson" SET "refCustomerId"=$1,"updatedAt"=$2 WHERE "id" IN ('[object Object]')
(node:11392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for integer: "[object Object]"

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what Anatoly posted.
I had method declared on TypeScript like:

```
declare addPost: HasManyCreateAssociationMixin<PostClass, 'userId'>;
```

When i changed to:

```
declare createPost: HasManyCreateAssociationMixin<PostClass, 'userId'>;
```

Everything works so remember - how you describe name of method its very necesary.